# Should I upgrade Magento before changing the theme?

Tags: magento, themes, upgrade, migrate

I have a Magento store running on 1.3.2.4 and the client wants to give the site a facelift.  
Would it be better to stay with the current version and just modify the current version or should I migrate to a newer version?
Additionally, is it possible to backup the existing store on ver. 1.3.2.4 and just do a fresh install of a newer version and restore?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading from 1.3.x to 1.6.x will not be as straight forward as you may think.

My suggestion is to setup a copy of your existing site, and attempt the upgrade **BEFORE** a redesign.  Unless your client is okay with staying with the same version of Magento.

You can also create a copy of the database and upload the latest version of Magento, you'll then need to copy over your app/etc/local.xml file from your installation and modify it to use your duplicate database.

More reading:

- http://www.nicksays.co.uk/2010/03/fool-proof-magento-upgrades/
- http://magentoexpert.com/upgrading-magento-from-1-3-2-4-to-1-5-or-1-6/
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/263068/#t355374

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be better to stay with the current version and just modify the current version or should I migrate to a newer version?

Modify the current version unless your client can pay you to perform the upgrade.

> Additionally, is it possible to backup the existing store on ver. 1.3.2.4 and just do a fresh install of a newer version and restore?

Of course.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of stuff changed in 1.4 with regards to the layout/design system. We had to change several things to get the update right so I'd suggest you upgrade first.